# R Shiny: Conditional labeling with geom_text

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, label, geom-text

In the following example I want to make use of conditional labeling.

If the salary is low, the text should be shown above the top of the bar. If the salary is high, it should be shown below the top of the bar (like it is already with geom_text(aes(label=text), vjust=-0.25)). The condition itself is working very well. But: The annotation should be shown as a string, i.e. "low", and "high". But in my case there is "1" and "2". I don't know where these numbers come from. Is there the possibility to show the text as string like it is contained in the data frame?

```
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("conditional label"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
    salary <- c(5000, 9000, 12000)
    text <- c('low', 'low', 'high')
    df <- data.frame(employee, salary, text)

    plot <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=employee, y=salary), color="black") +
      geom_bar(color="black", stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,13000)) +
      geom_text(aes(label=text), vjust=-0.25) +
      geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(salary > 10000, text, "")), vjust=1.5) +
      geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(salary < 10000, text, "")), vjust=-1.5)

    print(plot)


  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: geom_text - conditional labeling]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using `dplyr::if_else()` and `NULL` instead of `""`

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("conditional label"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),
        mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

        employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
        salary <- c(5000, 9000, 12000)
        text <- c('low', 'low', 'high')
        df <- data.frame(employee, salary, text)

        plot <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=employee, y=salary), color="black") +
            geom_bar(color="black", stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
            scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,13000)) +
            geom_text(aes(label=text), vjust=-0.25) +
            geom_text(aes(label = if_else(salary > 10000, text, NULL)), vjust=1.5) +
            geom_text(aes(label = if_else(salary < 10000, text, NULL)), vjust=-1.5)

        print(plot)


    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Update**

See improved answer using `ifelse()`:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("conditional label"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),
        mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

        employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
        salary <- c(5000, 9000, 12000)
        text <- c('low', 'low', 'high')
        df <- data.frame(employee, salary, text)

        plot <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=employee, y=salary), color="black") +
            geom_bar(color="black", stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
            scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,13000)) +
            geom_text(aes(label=text), vjust=-0.25) +
            geom_text(aes(label = text, vjust=ifelse(salary > 10000, 1.5, -1.5)))

        print(plot)


    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please just check the if statement of salary > 10000. Currently if it is equal it will be -1.5.

Comment: Works great. But how do I prevent the "Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_text)", which was not there before?

Comment: See updated answer above. Please just check that this works for your use case. The text doesn't change so I put the ifelse on the vjust.

Comment: I think the updated solution is better with regard to efficiency and readability. Thank you!

Comment: Agreed, initially I just answered your question but I now relooked at your actual use case holistically.